# LinkedIn Profile Update: should I mention, I dropped out?

Tags: linkedin

I started BS CS in 2009, dropped out in 2013 , readmission-ed (in same institute, same degree) in 2015. Completed my degree in 2017. Although I was readmission-ed in 2015, I was enrolled with the batch of 2012 (with  those who were enrolled in 2012 and graduated in 2016), which means I was late one more year with batch 2012.

Now I need to update my LinkedIn, without telling anyone that I dropped out (I  am ok with it, but bad society stigma).

Should I mention the dates from 2012-2017 (This is reasonable, according to me) or 2013 to 2017?

During this phase, I worked full-time, should I mention it?

Comment: Your wording is confusing here.  What years did you actually attend college for the degree course that you completed?  I'm not sure a reader of your profile will care what "batch" you were in, but would be more interested in when you graduated.

Comment: @Pete I am sorry for the text. I attended college  from 2009-2017 with  gap between 2013 to 2015

Comment: Neither 2012 nor 2013 is true though, it's either 2009 or 2015 (or both).

Comment: I recommend only showing your graduation year. If anyone really cares, it will give you a topic for conversation.

Answer (score 5):

Don't lie on your CV (LinkedIn is a form of CV), it could cause you more bother than it's worth, e.g. during a backgroud check.

Instead, when it comes to dates mention both sets:

> University of Blah
>
> Bachelor of sciences in Computer Science
>
> 2009-2013, 2015-2016

People take a gap year, it's a standard thing these days and you seem to be thinking there's a stigma when there really isn't. If anything, it gives a nice talking point during your interview where you can discuss why you left and came back. I'd be more impressed you had the determination to go back and finish the job. Lying to hide something that you shouldn't be ashamed off is daft and not needed.

Comment: thanks @Draken well I am from South Asia, huge social stigma for this1

Comment: @user7498776 [Can you edit your question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/98356/edit) and please add a country tag then? That tends to help us knowing what audience we're working with

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mention the exact word "Dropped out" in your profile. You can bring this up when you are in a discussion with a potential company to work for. instead of worrying about the gap you have created during your degree, you can emphasize on the things you have done during a full-time job you had in between.